# 3 column css, middle fixed size, right and left fluid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to render a 3 column design with the following :

- middle fixed width at 660px
- left and right half of the remaining but with min-width : 120px
- middle div should be centered on the screen

Everything I'm finding is about fixing left and right column and letting fluid the middle one, but I want the exact opposite.
I've partially achieved my goal using

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Akatsukle/Mnaam/1/).

What's missing is the right resizing of the right and left div. When the window get resized, 660/sizeofwindow is changing, so the value in percentage of the left and of the right div are no longer correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to achieve this.

It is a native CSS way to do simple math right in CSS as a replacement for any length value.

Please note that `calc` does not work with all browsers.

Write:

```
#left, #right {
    min-width:120px;
    width:calc(50% - 330px); // half of 660px
}
```

As you are using `display:inline-block`, make sure you don't leave any space between your div's because `inline-block` leaves white-space between elements.

See updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mnaam/3/) here.

Comment: nice one :) didn't know about the calc property

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hdt75/

```
.fenetre {
    text-align: center;
    width:1200px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin:  0 auto;
}
```

Comment: yes, it's a solution, but I didn't wanted to fix the size of the total

Comment: @Richard so what should happend when fenetre width is smaller then 1200px ? I've just change middle witdt to 660px please see here http://jsfiddle.net/E6xEG/ is that what you wanted ?

Comment: I don't get the 1200px; the problem is at 900px (660+120+120) no?
I don't know what's the best option when this is reach. Should the right div be put down, or should a scrollbar appear?

Comment: @Richard that depends. If you want desktop page fixed width is solution, but if you want page to be responsive you can't set fixed width but another but 660px for middle div is too much for some mobiles

Answer (score 1):

If you want table-like behavior, you should use `display: table-cell` in your CSS:

```
.fenetre {
    display: table-row;
}
.section {
    display: table-cell;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
}
#middle {
    min-width: 660px;
    max-width: 660px; // just 'width: 660px' won't be enough here
}    
#left {
    width: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zL9cn/